# Scrapy yielding requests with a depth of 2

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

So I am having trouble logging from a function that is 2 requests down from the starting `parse` method. Here is the code:

```
from datetime import datetime
import scrapy
import requests
import re
import os


class ScrapyTest(scrapy.Spider):
    """
    Generic crawler
    """
    name = "test"
    start_urls = [
            'http://www.reddit.com',
    ]

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ScrapyTest, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def parse(self, response):
        """
        Entry point for the crawler
        """
        self.logger.debug('starting off in the parse function')
        yield scrapy.Request(self.start_urls[0], callback=self.parse_hw_post)

    def parse_hw_images(self, image_links):
        self.logger.debug("inside parse_hw_images about to scrapy request parse_hw_image")
        yield scrapy.Request(self.start_urls[0], callback=self.parse_hw_image)

    def parse_hw_image(self, response):
        self.logger.debug('inside ________internal________ parse hw image')
        yield 'test string to yield in to'

    def parse_hw_post(self, response):
        # Save the images to a tmp directory for now
        self.logger.debug('in parse_hw_post')
        self.parse_hw_images('whatever')
```

Now the only logging that shows up is the `Starting off in the parse function` and then `inside parse_hw_images about to scrapy request parse_hw_image`

Expected behavior would be:

1. parse
2. parse_hw_post
3. parse_hw_images
4. parse_hw_image

Can anyone see what is off with what I'm doing?

Comment: You yield a `Request` which calls `self.parse` itself in `self.parse` method. That's an implicit infinite loop.

Comment: Hey sraw, I've fixed the example and clarified the intent of workflow

Answer (score 1):

`yield scrapy.Request(self.start_urls[0], callback=self.parse)` means you are calling same `parse` method with same URL so scrapy is filtering it as duplicate URL.

Set `DUPEFILTER_DEBUG=True` to see duplicate URLs.

Comment: Hey Umair, thanks for the point out! However the problem still stands and I've clarified the intent of my workflow. Would love to get some help for this if you can provide!

Answer (score 0):

```
def parse_hw_post(self, response):
    # Save the images to a tmp directory for now
    self.logger.debug('in parse_hw_post')

    for req in self.parse_hw_images('whatever'):
        yield req
```

Comment: Is there no way to yield when inside a yield?

Comment: @Recur it's not a function but a generator https://jeffknupp.com/blog/2013/04/07/improve-your-python-yield-and-generators-explained/

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean though. 
Which number is going wrong for me under the list of `Expected behavior` in my original post?

I've used a ipdb to step in to code and it goes in to `parse_hw_images` but doesn't execute the first line of that function. it just shows that it's entered that function and goes off to some event loop that scrapy's probably implemented.